# The version number of the Emacs after 24.4

Tags: emacs24.4

I've seen a lot of references to:

- Emacs 25
- Emacs 24.5

I tend to think that the next emacs will be Emacs 25, because that's what the git version of emacs calls itself, but I keep *hearing* about 24.5, even recently from knowledgeable developers.

I've been looking for a source to resolve this, but I haven't found anything.

Which is it? (Would like a source with reliable references.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `trunk` of Emacs' git repository will be released as Emacs 25.1, whenever it is ready. But there is also a branch in git called `emacs-24`, which gets bug solutions. This might (or might not, who knows) end up in Emacs 24.5. Commits to `emacs-24` are merged to `trunk` from time to time.

Comment: Interesting. That definitely explains better why some people still reference a 24.5.

Answer (score 6):

[According to Stefan Monnier it's going to be 25.1](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2014-09/msg00872.html).

Comment: Well. Now we know it [was released](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.24.5?utm_content=buffer1ed7a&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) as 24.5